# Split-Path on a selected string

Tags: powershell

Essentially I want all the information I can produce below to be in the same variable.  Currently I have it in 2 pieces.  I would like to get the output from the `Split-Path` as a new column titled "folder" in the `$newdata` variable.

```
$newdata = gci -r C:\temp\Screenshots\*.* |
           ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt '12/30/16'} |
           % {Get-ItemProperty $_} |
           select BaseName, Directory

$newdata | select Directory | % {
  Split-Path (Split-Path "$_" -Parent) -Leaf
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) are for.

```
$newdata = Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\temp\Screenshots\*.* |
           Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt '12/30/16'} |
           ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_} |
           Select-Object BaseName, Directory,
             @{n='Folder';e={Split-Path $_.Directory -Parent | Split-Path -Leaf}}
```

Comment: one slight alteration a ";" instead of a "," between 'Folder',e.  But yes, this is what I was looking for thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. Fixed.